# Python3: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, typeerror

I am trying to build up a Huffman tree for a practice, and my code building a tuple keeps telling me that I got a **TypeError: 'list' object is not callable** for this following code:

```
  def buildTree(mylist) :
    while len(mylist) > 1 :
    leastTwo = tuple(mylist[0:2])   <<<<<<<< problematic line             
    theRest  = mylist[2:]                          
    combFreq = leastTwo[0][0] + leastTwo[1][0]     
    mylist   = theRest + [(combFreq,leastTwo)]     
    mylist.sort()                                  
    return mylist[0]
```

**Update: The input Mylist would be a list with tuples like this: [(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'g'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'a'), (5, 'e')]**

I have been trying to debug for a while yet none of my solutions really works. I am following the instruction from *http://www.openbookproject.net/py4fun/huffman/huffman.html*, which does exactly the same thing as I did, so I am not sure what went wrong especially for me.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should post your call to `buildTree(...)`; we don't know what `mylist` _is_.

Comment: You have apparently assigned a list to the name `tuple` at some previous point in your code, overriding the built-in type.

Comment: Make sure your code in the question match your actual code. In Python, whitespace (i.e. space, tab and newlines) are important for how the code executes.

Comment: Thats why you shouldn't use built-in function names as var names ;)

Comment: Try `tuple(*mylist[0:2])`

Comment: @Jacob just added it!

Comment: @RafaelC is mylist also a built-in function name? I avoided using list and use it  :(

Comment: `mylist` is ok but `tuple` isn't

Comment: @jasonharper omg yes, I did a typo in the test and that is why I couldn't find the error. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @RafaelC Yes, just find the error in my test case instead of my implementation. That explains why I couldn't find it at all. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: this code can't work in it's current state.

Comment: It actually works in my case after I changed my problematic var name. Can you paste the error you got here so I can check?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you needed:

```
def buildTree(mylist) :
    while len(mylist) > 1 :
        leastTwo = tuple(mylist[0:2])
        combFreq = leastTwo[0][0] + leastTwo[1][0]     
        mylist   = sorted(mylist[2:] + [(combFreq,leastTwo)], key=lambda a: a[0])
    return mylist[0]

mylist =  [(1, 'b'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'g'), (2, 'c'), (2, 'f'), (3, 'a'), (5, 'e')]
print(buildTree(mylist) )
```

The end result looks like:

```
(15, ((6, ((3, 'a'), (3, ((1, 'g'), (2, 'c'))))), (9, ((4, ((2, 'f'), (2, ((1, 'b'), (1, 'd'))))), (5, 'e')))))
```